# How do I implement an auto-running script on Google Apps Script in another person's table without my access?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to implement an automatic script in the client's google table, I open the script editor in client's table, write the necessary functions, set triggers by time and everything works fine. The problem is that clients want confidentiality, so after implementation they close my access to the table. But this stops the execution of all scripts in the client table, error: "Exception: You do not have permission to access this document.".
Is there an easy way to fix this?
I found options with a web application and a library, but I do not understand well in their implementation and:

1. In a web application, if I understand correctly, I cannot make the execution of script functions at the time intervals I need
2. The library spends more time when executing the script than the script itself, which is important for large amounts of data

I'm an inexperienced developer, so I might be wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest/best solution, if they want confidentiality, is to walk the client through setting up the triggers, so that the code runs under their account.

Alternatively, have them create a Google account with access to the sheet and share the credentials with you, configure the triggers from that account, and once it's operational they can change the password.